# Remove list within a list and change encoding

Tags: python

I have a list in Python 2.7 that looks like this.

`[[u'ABC'], [u'DEF'], [u'GHI']]`

Now, I want to convert it so it should be like this.

`['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']`

How can I do this?

Comment: There are two components to this, have you researched either of them?

Comment: Not even sure what the second component is, this is really just flattening a list. It’s questionable why you think the leading `u` should be removed at all.

Comment: `[val[0] for val in [[u'ABC'], [u'DEF'], [u'GHI']]]` will do, but please move to Python 3!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list is named `arr` you can do `arr = [i[0].encode('ascii') for i in arr]`. **Note** this assumes that each element is a list of only (and at least) one item and that you aren't concerned about there being non-ASCII characters in the string

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Python. This is just flattening a list

```
flattened_list = [val[0] for val in [[u'ABC'], [u'DEF'], [u'GHI']]]
print(flattened_list)
```

By the way please move to Python 3!